# Dynamic React Pagination using Hooks

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-hooks

i implemented a simple pagination component using hooks but now i want to make pagination dynamic i have tried so many things but nothing works

< 1 2 3 4 5 >

< 2 3 4 5 6 >

i want to implement something like this. now all the page numbers are showing 
 please note that page count is coming from back end

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Pagination = ({ setCurrentPage, currentPage, pageCount }) => {

  const pageNumbers = [];

  const [styleClass, setStyleClass] = useState('active')

 
  for (var i = 1; i <=pageCount; i++) {
      pageNumbers.push(i)
  }

  function paginate(page) {
    if (page >= 1) {
      let pagenumber = page - 1
      setCurrentPage(pagenumber)
    }

  }


  function firstPage() {
    setCurrentPage(0)
  }

  function lastPage() {
    setCurrentPage(pageCount - 1)
  }

  function next() {
    if (pageNumbers.length - 1 > currentPage) {
      let page = currentPage;
      let next = page + 1;
      setCurrentPage(next)
    }
  }

  function back() {
    if (currentPage >= 1) {
      let page = currentPage;
      let back = page - 1;
      setCurrentPage(back)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="pagination">
      <a onClick={() => { firstPage() }} >First</a>
      <a onClick={() => { back() }} >&laquo;</a>
      {
        pageNumbers.map(page => {
          return (
            <a key={page} onClick={() => { paginate(page) }} className={page - 1 === currentPage ? styleClass : ''} >{page}</a>
          )
        })
      }
      <a onClick={() => { next() }} >&raquo;</a>
      <a onClick={() => { lastPage() }}>Last</a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pagination;
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably already took another solution for this issue.

I was facing the same problem and I found this "Sequence generator"

using the method Array.from() combined with a callback function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#sequence_generator_range

You can get the length of the pages using your data length divided by the amount of record you want to show per page (amount).

ex)

```
const _yourData_ = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]; // data length: 16
const fetchOptions = {
    page: 1,
    amount: 10
};
const pageLen = Math.ceil(_yourData_.length / fetchOptions.amount);

// console.log(pageLen); 
// 2

const pageRange = Array.from({
length: pageLen
}, (v, i) => i + 1); 

// console.log(pageRange);
// [1, 2]
```

Now you can use .map function with this `pageRange` to render each page item component.

Hope it helps!